# Calculating standard errors for contrasts of parameter estimates of a (multiple) linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, matlab, t-test, standard-error, contrasts

I am running regression analyses in matlab with glmfit and calculate significance of contrasts of parameter estimates by using standard errors. Somehow however, the results I get are not consistent with SPSS results, so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Hence 2 Questions:

1. Can somebody point me to a source where the equations/formulas for of t-tests and F tests for contrasts of parameter estimates is described?
2. It would also be great if somebody could have a look of my code, to see if there is maybe something obviously wrong (see below).

#### code

Note: as this is matlab code, matrix algebra applies.

1) Calculate sigma square from residuals and degrees of freedom (stats.residp is a vector):

`sigma_squared = (stats.residp'*stats.residp)/stats.dfe;`

2) Get the variance for a contrast through multiplication with covariance of regressors (stats.covb) and contrast vector (c, which is actually a matrix with many contrasts):

`var_c = sigma_squared*c'*stats.covb*c;`

3) Get the standard error by taking the square root of the diagonal of the matrix of contrast-variances:

`se_c = sqrt(diag(var_c));`

4) Calculate t-statistic (c,b,se_c are vectors; ./ makes the division an element by element division):

`t = (c'*b)./se_c;`

5) Get the p value by plugging the t statistic in the cumulative student t distribution with the right degrees of freedom:

`p = 2*((1-tcdf(t,stats.dfe)).*(t>0) + (tcdf(t,stats.dfe)).*(t<0));`

Comment: So that we can understand the problem, please provide a small example showing how the Matlab results differ from the SPSS results.